# mysql export table but no database

Tags: mysql

write mysql order try to export a table to my D disk and save it as a .sql file,the order is:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqldump -u root -p facebbook_info fb_group_members_about > D:\fb_group_members_about.sql
Enter password: ********
```

but it errors:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'facebbook_info' when selecting the database

however ,in mysql order window:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| facebook_info      |
| mysql              |
| mysql_test         |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

there is database: facebook_info, could you please tell me the reason and how resolve it

Comment: you have written facebbook with two b in your statement. Use `mysqldump -u root -p facebook_info fb_group_members_about`

Answer (score 1):

You have written `facebbook_info` with two b in your command. Use

```
mysqldump -u root -p facebook_info fb_group_members_about
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use following command to export database

mysqldump -u root -p facebook_info > location-of-directroy/name.sql