# Mysqldump - Error 1049 unknown database [db] when selecting the database

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm running MySQL in Linux Red Hat 7. I've got an existing database, `error.db`, which I copied over to my MySQL directory, and now I want to import it into MySQL. I found [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb) which recommended using `mysqldump` to export the database to an .sql file, which I can then source in the MySQL client.

So I tried the following:

```
$ mysqldump --socket=socket -u root -p error.db > error_db.sql
```

After entering the password, I received this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'error.db' when selecting the database
```

I'm definitely in the correct directory, `error.db` definitely exists, and I've definitely typed the password in correctly. I've tried adding the -d flag and the --databases flag, and that hasn't worked. I've also tried using `error` instead of `error.db`, and that hasn't worked.

I've checked other questions and haven't found a working solution. This one, the problem was caused by a typo (which I know is not the case:) [mysql export table but no database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094870/mysql-export-table-but-no-database).

And this one was solved because the OP was putting the password in the command line, and apparently using the -p flag solved their problem (although as you can see, I'm using the -p flag and it's still not working:) [MYSQL DBDump Error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811029/mysql-dbdump-error-message)

I'm using a Load Sharing Facility at work to run MySQL, but that hasn't stopped me from using another .sql file to load a database into MySQL, so I'm not sure whether that would make a difference.

**EDIT:** Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql), I've tried using `mysql` instead of `mysqldump`, but still no luck:

```
mysql --socket=socket -u root -p error.db > error_db.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'error.db'
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

**EDIT 2:** The `error.db` database is in SQLite3. I had assumed that the database types would be cross-compatible, but probably this was an incorrect assumption. So I guess my question is how to convert an SQLite3 database to MySQL.

Comment: I am about contents of 'error.db'.  How was this file created? if it is readable, can you share the first couple of lines of it?

Comment: *`error.db` definitely exists* Do you really see `error.db` in the output of `SHOW DATABASES;` command?

Comment: @Akina - No, it doesn't show up in MySQL using `SHOW DATABASES` - the point is that I'm trying to import it into MySQL, after first exporting it to an .sql file. I mean that the `error.db` file definitely exists in the directory I'm working in, and the directory from which I started MySQL.

Comment: *I mean that the error.db file definitely exists in the directory I'm working in, and the directory from which I started MySQL.* This file is NOT a database. This is regular file which cannot be dumped via MySQL. use common file copy procedure.

Comment: @Luuk - The file was originally created for SQLite3 - I forgot to mention. I believe I populated it by parsing a plain text file using Perl, then outputting into an SQLite3 database.

Comment: @Akina What is "common file copy procedure" here?

Comment: If this is SQLite database, and you need to import it to MySQL, you must convert its data from SQLite database format to some format which is clear for MySQL or use the convertor utility/script. There is a lot of questions about converting/migrating from SQLite to MySQL there - search...

Comment: I can't say that you were 100% cooperative in your approach, but you did technically point me in the direction of the right answer, so +1 and cheers :)

Comment: `sqlite3 error.db .dump > error.sql`  might get you started to create a file ('error.sql') which migth be importable into Mysql.   I think you first need to create ta database in MySQL (`CREATE DATABASE error`) before bein able to do an import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the problem was because I was trying to open a database created in SQLite using MySQL. In retrospect I probably should've seen that that would be an issue.

The solution I took was to export the file in SQLite3 to a CSV file, by opening `error.db` in SQLite3, and using this code:

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output error_data.csv
```

([Source](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-export-csv/))

Then I opened MySQL using:

```
mysql --socket=socket -u root -p --local-infile error
```

I created the database `error` and the table `error`, and then ran the following commands, which successfully imported the data from the .csv file into my database:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'error_data.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE error
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
Query OK, 920 rows affected, 627 warnings (0.05 sec)
Records: 920  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 627
```

Thanks to @mpoletto from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql) and the OP from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-do-i-import-csv-file-into-a-mysql-table) for helping me figure all that out.

I don't know why there were warnings; I was unable to check them as I had already run a select query before I knew that you had to run `SHOW WARNINGS` immediately after the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **mysqldump --socket=socket -u root -p --databases error.db > error_db.sql** command instead of **mysqldump --socket=socket -u root -p error.db > error_db.sql**